# An error of using maven release plugin

Tags: svn, tags, maven-release-plugin

My project architecture is like this:

```
--Parent
  --Submodule1
  --Submodule2
--pom.xml(main)
```

Parent is the project which hold all maven plugins configuration, librairies version etc. It's the parent of all project which is the parent of all submodules.
I configure plugin in pom.xml(main),like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <tagBase>svn://192.168.5.213/hxbos/hxecp-src/tags/hxbos</tagBase>
    <branchBase>svn://192.168.5.213/hxbos/hxecp-src/branches/hxbos</branchBase>
    <remotetagging>true</remotetagging>
    <checkModificationExcludes>
      <checkModificationExclude>**/*.log</checkModificationExclude>
      <checkModificationExclude>**/*.jar</checkModificationExclude>
      <checkModificationExclude>**/system*</checkModificationExclude>
    </checkModificationExcludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and this is my scm info:

```xml
<scm>
  <connection>scm:svn:svn://192.168.5.213/hxbos/hxecp-src/trunk/hxbos</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:svn:svn://192.168.5.213/hxbos/hxecp-src/trunk/hxbos</developerConnection>
  <url>scm:svn:svn://192.168.5.213/hxbos/hxecp-src/trunk/hxbos</url>
</scm>
```

but when I use:mvn release:prepare,an error occurs:

```
 The svn tag command failed.
 Command output:
 svn: “svn://192.168.5.213/hxbos/hxecp-src/trunk/hxbos” does not exist in 
 revision 0.
```

why is revision 0?

Comment: Cause the repository does not exist. Check if on the machine with the given IP address has a repository under /hxbos/hxecp-src ..

Comment: I am sure the repository exit,and we are using.

Comment: Does this help? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/faq.html#inheritScm

Comment: thanks,I already have read the FAQ,little help!the revision is 0,why?

Comment: Do you have scm elements in all the child projects?

Comment: Does it nessary?I hava try,but also failed.Then I find this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402150/where-placed-the-scm-tag?s=573c823d-7b31-45de-8948-c45d75b0aa1b#new-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few things to check:

- My SCM URLs look something like this:

  scm:svn:https://subversion.company.com/svn/maven/trunk/corporate-parent

Note the `https` part; you show `scm:svn:svn`, not sure how that works.

- One place that has tripped me up before: I checked out an existing project using an https protocol but the POM had 'http' in its SCM connection block.  The mismatch caused problems at release time.  So, make the protocol you used for the checkout match the SCM connection in the POM.  If you did

  `svn checkout http://192.168.5.213/hxbos/hxecp-src/trunk/hxbos`

then your SCM block should look something like this:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://192.168.5.213/hxbos/hxecp-src/trunk/hxbos</connection>
</scm>
```

- If you are doing a multi-module build, define SCM blocks in all your POMs, don't let them be inherited from the parent POM.
- Last but not least, make sure you are using the latest version of the release plugin.

---

EDIT: use the http: or https: (whichever you used to perform the original checkout) in the tagBase and branchBase URLs too.  I notice that you have the "svn:" prefix in those URLs.  The [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#tagBase) for `tagBase` say "For example, `http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/plugins/tags`. The URL is an SVN URL and does not include the SCM provider and protocol."

Comment: Thank you,I have tried all of what you said,but failed again,I am going crazy.

Comment: What version of svn did you use to check out the code?  If you run mvn with `-X`, can you see what version of svn Maven is using?  Maybe there is a mismatch there.

Comment: maven version:3.0.4
svn version:1.5
plugin version:2.3.2